# Removing half-installed Ubuntu & re installing it again

Tags: re-installation

I was upgrading to a new version of Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 12.04.  Suddenly my power went out half way through the installation, and it could not complete.  On start-up I see versions of Ubuntu 2.6.32.41-generic, but when I select that it shows no disc found and Ubuntu screen stand still.  I don't know how to solve  this.

Is it possible to remove the existing install completely and install again?

Comment: Is formatting the drive an option?

Comment: no i don lik to format.i installed fresh copy of 10.04 again but it installed in a new partition so the old version is in another parition.. if i upgrade now to 12.04 will it be solved?? is there any way to format the uninstalled old version alone ?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to make fresh install of ubuntu 12.04 but if you want to upgrade... download ubuntu 12.04 from site.. Burn installation disk. and upgrade through it.

Comment: i installed fresh copy of 10.04 again but it installed in a new partition so the old version is in another parition.. if i upgrade now to 12.04 will it be solved?? is there any way to format the uninstalled old version alone ?

Answer (score 0):

I think not, because if you now upgrade the version it will affect the new partition, so it wont have any effect on old partition. Then:

- You can extract the data from old partition using new installation you have, ***or***
- You can boot to Ubuntu terminal by specifying the proper boot parameters in the GRUB2 boot loader. You must know the UUID of the partition containing your previous installation ***or*** the recovery console. Once you have access to the broken Ubuntu system, just use `sudo apt-get ...` commands to fix the problem. (In particular, try `sudo apt-get -f install` followed by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.)

As you have already downloaded the required distribution packages, it will simply update the system.

Answer (score 0):

According Me, remove both that Partitions and fresh install 12.04. Your bandwidth will be more wasted in upgrading 10.04 to 12.04 and it may be not smooth. so download fresh Iso of 12.04 and install.